# Question about transaction confirmation

Tags: blockchain, ethereumjs

My question is that when a miner broadcast some transactions and other nodes don't think these transactions are valid, what will happen? Fork?

Answer (score 0):

Other nodes simply don't care about the bad block and continue with some other block. The bad miner has two options: either continue mining on top of the bad block or try to mine a valid block. If he continues on top of the bad block no other node still won't accept any of those blocks as even if subsequent blocks are valid they are based on an invalid block so they also become invalid.

So a minor fork can happen if the bad miner decides to continue his bad branch but in reality there's no point in trying such so nobody really does it. But from the main blockchain's point of view there is no fork as they don't even consider the block as ever being part of the blockchain.